# Django CreateView and validation

Tags: django, validation

I'm trying to implement generic views in my Django 1.8 app, so that Django can take care of the validation/redirection loop for me.

I've created a model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    custid = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='CID (4 alphanumeric uppercase)', validators=[validators.CIDValidator])
    customer_shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=7, verbose_name='Customer Code (7 chars, uppercase, no spaces)', validators=[validators.ShortnameValidator])
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

and defined a validator for each of my two validated fields:

```
class CIDValidator(RegexValidator):
    regex = r'^[A-Z0-9]{4}$'
    message = 'CID is a 4-character uppercase alphanumeric value'

class ShortnameValidator(RegexValidator):
    regex = r'^[A-Z0-9_]{1,7}$'
    message = 'Shortname should be uppercase, no spaces, alphanumeric'
```

(At this point, I expected that the admin interface would use the validators when I added a Customer, but it doesn't)

For the actual app, I've created a ModelForm for the Customer class:

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = Customer
            fields = ['custid', 'customer_shortcode', 'description']
```

and a View class inherited from CreateView:

```
class CustomerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Customer
    form_class = CustomerForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('customer_list')
```

And I still don't get validation errors when I enter invalid data in the generated form.

As far as I can follow from the docs, I should only need to override clean() or clean_xxx() on the ModelForm for *additional* validation, not for this, but it's really unclear. I'd like to keep the knowledge about what constitutes a valid value in as few places as possible - which the validator on the ModelField would do.

What is missing here? I suspect I'm getting confused between model validation and form validation...

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform

Comment: @chandu - right, and I'm reading "model form validation is triggered implicitly".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: when specifying this kind of validators in model field definitions, you should pass instances rather than classes (`validators.CIDValidator()` instead of `validators.CIDValidator`).

**Longer explanation**

Django validators [need to be callables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#writing-validators). Trying to call the class you are passing now will go through python's creation sequence for an instance, calling `__new__` and `__init__`, and it would return  an instance of that class - but it won't do anything in terms of validating the field value.

The Django validators you are subclassing also have a `__call__` method, that is run when you try to call an instance of that class, and it takes care of validating and raising `ValidationError`s

Comment: Thank you, Sir! Both CBV and admin are validating now.